# Como construir URLs amigáveis, como do Facebook e Twitter.

Tags: php, mysql, htaccess

Estou com uma dúvida, como posso construir links como o Facebook e Twitter? Por exemplo: `http://facebook.com/nome-qualquer`.

Sei que o `.htaccess` trata de certa forma a url, porém, a questão que estou batendo cabeça é como carregar o conteúdo da url `http://fb.com/fulano-de-tal`

Pego tudo após a última barra e é feito uma consulta na SQL com `fulano-de-tal` e então é retornado o resultado?

Answer (score 2):

Em seu HTACCESS você deve definir algo como

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ profiles.php?name=$1
```

Ai no seu arquivo **profiles.php** você recupera o parâmetro **$name** e busca as informações no banco de dados a respeito daquela pessoa q queira exibir naquela página

assim sua url ficaria algo como

*www.seusite.com/tchicotti*

mas na verdade seu site estaria sendo acesso dessa maneira:

**www.seusite.com/profiles.php?name=tchicotti**

Answer (score 1):

## Rotas

O que você está tentando fazer é o que chamamos hoje em dia de **rotas** (*routes*).

Quando você faz a utilização de algum Framework, a maioria deles, já contém essa funcionalidade por padrão, tornando o gerenciamento das rotas muito mais fácil.

Nada impede que você crie um `.htaccess` e defina suas rotas, porém fica menos amigável e pode dificultar a manutenção.

Você pode criar no `.htaccess` uma rota para que tudo depois da barra (`site.com.br/`) seja direcionado para um arquivo em específico, e nesse arquivo você pode fazer o tratamento que desejar, seja com um simples `if` ou algo mais sofisticado.

Segue um exemplo:

### **.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

// tudo que cair em /usuarios/usuario-x => será redirecionado para usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^usuarios/(\d+)*$ ./usuarios.php?id=$1

// o mesmo acontece com essas \/
RewriteRule ^posts/(\d+)*$ ./usuarios.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^comunidades/(\d+)*$ ./comunidades.php?id=$1
```

### **usuarios.php**

```
<?php
    // aqui você irá encontrar os dados e tratar da forma que desejar.
    print_r($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
?>
```

Veja como funciona o sistema de rotas de alguns Frameworks:

- **Ruby on Rails** - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- **Laravel** - http://laravel.com/docs/controllers