# Dificuldade com reescrita de URLs amigáveis

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Não tenho grande experiência com .htaccess e estou tendo algumas dificuldades para reescrever as URLS de um site.

No site em questão, primeiro forcei a reescrita da URL para HTTPS (o site não possuía SSL antes):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.dominio.com.br/pagina404.html
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Depois efetuei o redirecionamento 301 de *dominio.com.br* para *www.dominio.com.br* com sucesso. A regra também se aplica a index ou index.php depois da URL base (ex: *www.dominio.com.br/index.php*).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio\.com\.br
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.dominio.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index(/|.php)?$ https://www.dominio.com.br [R=301,L]
```

Até aqui, tudo funcionou. Ocorre que as URLs deste site não são amigáveis. Elas seguem o padrão abaixo:
*www.dominio.com.br/index.php?link=sobre*

Como a reescrita remove o index, elas ficam assim:
*www.dominio.com.br/?link=sobre*

Então eu forço a reescrita usando o snippet mais abaixo, para tentar uma URL assim:
*www.dominio.com.br/sobre*

```
RewriteRule ^\?link=(.*) /$1
RewriteRule ^/(.*)(.php)?\?link=(.*) /$3
```

Essa foi uma das regras que tentei, inclusive testando no Sublime/netBeans, usando o módulo de *regex* deles, dando certo lá. Ocorre que quando teste no servidor, não ocorre reescrita.
Testei diversas outras regras lendo a documentação, como o [NC],[L] entre outros. Alguns resultam em erro 500.

Então minha dúvida é se o uso do HTTPs, a supressão do index ou o próprio servidor pode estar afetando estas reescritas?

Nota: eu tentei algumas das opções mostradas em outros tópicos, como essas:

[Exemplo 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9219/como-construir-urls-amig%C3%A1veis-como-do-facebook-e-twitter)
[Exemplo 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27735/htaccess-reescrevendo-url-n%C3%A3o-amig%C3%A1vel)

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [**resposta 1**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28076/13412), [**resposta 2**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27535/13412)

Comment: [Implementando URL amigáveis com roteamento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95310/url-amigavel-dinamica/98403?noredirect=1#comment200509_98403)

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você vai fazer o *HTACCESS* mandar para o PHP rotear a URL. Não é necessário fazer como querystring pois o PHP vai usar *REQUEST_URI* para rotear a requisição.

<sub>**.HTACCESS**</sub>

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```

<sub>**ROTA**</sub>

```
function router(){
    // www.domain.com/empresa/sobre
    $url = ltrim( parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , PHP_URL_PATH ) , '/' );
    return explode( '/' , $url );
}
```

<sub>**USO**</sub>

```
// array(0 => 'empresa' , 1 => 'sobre' )
$router = router();
```

---

Prefiro rotear baseado na `REQUEST_URI` para não colidir valores da *$_GET*.

Essa formas de rotear a URL é simples e mantém a lógica no PHP, toda informação da sua URL vai estar no array `router`, você decide como verificar os índices de `$router[X]`.

Comment: eu posso efetuar este tratamento em um arquivo config.php, por exemplo, ou através de uma função?

Comment: Pode der uma função normal: `$rotas = router()`, vou adicionar o exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Em relação ao HTTPS, não é recomendado realizar um redirect 301 para isso, devido ao SEO.

Para isso basta habilitar o HSTS no Apache2.
Com o HSTS habilitado, toda a navegação do usuário nos seu domínio/subdomínio será realizada via HTTPS.

Obs.: Esté método é utilizado pelo google, twitter, facebook, etc.
Referência: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Quanto a questão da rota é como o Papa Charlie recomendou, você vai passar o REQUEST_URI para o PHP e dentro da aplicação que você vai fazer as rotas.

O CakePHP é um framework que trabalha desta forma.